# how to set the array list in a listview builder in flutter?

Tags: arrays, flutter, flutter-listview

I have array fetched from firestore database successfully, for which I am trying to build a list for array using `ListView.builder` but not able to do so.

here is the array list I have

```
[{step: ffg}, {step: fgsgg}, {step: fgfda}]
```

**code for list view builder**

```
                   Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: widget.steps.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                                  
                                  child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      
                                      Text(
                                        //"STEPS ${index + 1}",
                                        "${widget.steps}",
                                        

                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Here is the screenshot of the result I am getting
[image: Result ScreenShot]

I want the list of array fetched in a serialized manner index wise. How am I suppose to achive it?
This is how I want the list to be displayed

1. ffg
2. fgsgg
3. fgfda

Comment: How you want it to be displayed is not clear. Clarify how you want the layout to be.

Comment: @JigarPatel I have updated the question above to display the list, it's in the end part of the question

Comment: can you show What is widget.steps?

Comment: @Haryanvi yes it is the array list in the above part of the question

Comment: Ok . Hope you got ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference an index within the array in the builder. `widget.steps` is using the default `toString` method of `List` to put convert it to a `String`.

And if you want to not use the default `toString` of `Map`(which is what is contained at each `List` reference), reference the `Map` item you want to show as well.

Both reference operators for these object are `[]`

```dart
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: widget.steps.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "${widget.steps[index]['step']}",//Reference an index & key here. This is why index is provided as a parameter in this callback
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using a `Column`..

```
Column(
      children: widget.steps.map((item){
        return Text('${item['step']}');
      }).toList(),
    )
```

..or using a `ListView.builder` like this..

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.steps.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
        return Text('${widget.steps[index]['step']}');
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Text( "${widget.steps[index]['step']}",)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your response `widget.steps` is a List of type Map so to get what's inside the list:

1. you have to define the index number
2. select the key to get its value

Try this: `Text("${widget.steps[index][step]}")`